# ASP.Net MVC4 RC Web-Api Odata filter not working with IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.net MVC4 RC's Web-api, I had a Get action defined like before:

```
public IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        var lst = ctx.GetListFromDB();
        return lst.AsQueryable();
    }
```

When it was I was running it before if I called a url like:
`/api/people?$inlinecount=allpages&$format=json&$top=50&$filter=(State+eq+'AL'+and+Zip+eq+'35242')`

It would do the filtering on the objects, has something changed since the beta that would break this?

Comment: I found the solution here http://forums.asp.net/t/1809900.aspx/1?Web+API+OData+in+RC

Comment: Check out the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  It's OK, and even encouraged, to answer your own question.  You might even get some points for doing so.

Comment: You should really go in and change @MartinF's answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to put the [Queryable] attribute on the method to allow filtering.  The release notes describing the change [are here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc317096197).

Update:
In RTM they seem to have separated this feature into its own assembly so you have to include a reference to the ASP.NET Web API OData assembly from Microsoft. You can find the latest version on Nuget
https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData

Update: 
In the latest version the Queryable attribute have been renamed to EnableQuery.
For more information about changes see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx

Comment: I've just tried and was not able to install this package, NuGet PS client claims package is missing, but it still seen on NuGet web site..

Comment: Did you ensure that the "Include Prerelease" option was selected?

Comment: worked for me, Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -Version 4.0.30506

Comment: This [Queryable] is now obsolete, I used [System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQuery] instead.

Answer (score 10):

So, apparently this feature has been removed from the final release schedule. I guess that means we'll need to modify existing WebAPI action methods to include the necessary filtering, sorting, and paging parameters for now. Very sad indeed.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/af11adf6b3c5

Comment: "we plan to provide much better OData support as a separate feature based on the OData library." sounds like they were unhappy with the current implementation.

Comment: See the other comment.  Just add the [Queryable] attribute and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see (on 9/20/12) you need the https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/0.1.0-alpha-120815 Nuget package to get this to work. Unfortunately, it's still in pre-release. 
The [Queryable] attribute is in this package.

I haven't found very good information on this.